# How do you pull text from a website into a dict?

Tags: python, parsing, text, web, html

I'm attempting to get the information from http://xkcd.com/info.0.json. Basically it looks like a simple python dictionary and that's what I'd like to convert it to. My current code is:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://xkcd.com/info.0.json') as response:
    html = [response.read()]
print(html)
```

and that outputs

```
[b'{"month": "2", "num": 1647, "link": "", "year": "2016", "news": "", "safe_title": "Diacritics", "transcript": "", "alt": "Using diacritics correctly is not my fort\\u00c3\\u00a9.", "img": "http:\\/\\/imgs.xkcd.com\\/comics\\/diacritics.png", "title": "Diacritics", "day": "24"}']
```

Answer (score 4):

You are receiving a JSON encoded response. You can parse that with the [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function:

```
import json
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://xkcd.com/info.0.json') as response:
    data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf8'))

>>> data
{'link': '', 'transcript': '', 'month': '2', 'year': '2016', 'alt': 'Using diacritics correctly is not my fortÃ©.', 'num': 1647, 'img': 'http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/diacritics.png', 'day': '24', 'safe_title': 'Diacritics', 'news': '', 'title': 'Diacritics'}
```

This is easier with the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) module:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://xkcd.com/info.0.json')
data = response.json()

>>> data
{'link': '', 'transcript': '', 'month': '2', 'year': '2016', 'alt': 'Using diacritics correctly is not my fortÃ©.', 'num': 1647, 'img': 'http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/diacritics.png', 'day': '24', 'safe_title': 'Diacritics', 'news': '', 'title': 'Diacritics'}
```

`requests` saves you the hassle of decoding the incoming data and decoding the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7 you need to `import urllib2` and then `import json` to load the data into a variable as a Python dictionary. Resource [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib2
import json
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://xkcd.com/info.0.json')
html = response.read().decode('utf8')

data = json.loads(html)
type(data) is dict # True
```